# Open multiple xml files, and parse them

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I need your help.
I'm trying to read many xlm files from just one folder, and I need to extract some information of each xml. These xml have the same structure.

At this point I can read each XML file, but just capture the information of the last one opened. How can I capture the information of each xml file and saved into a dataframe structure with pandas?

**This is my code:**

```
from os import listdir, path
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mypath = '/Users/nicolasdiaz/Desktop/dtes copy'
files = [path.join(mypath, f) for f in listdir(mypath) if f.endswith('.xml')]

for file in files:
    print(file)
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()

for docID in root.iter('Folio'):
    Invoice = 'Factura:' + docID.text
    print(Invoice)
for client_rut in root.iter('RUTRecep'):
    Rut = 'Rut:' + client_rut.text
    print(Rut)
```

**And this is my result:**, but I need the information of the three xml files

```
/Users/nicolasdiaz/venv/bin/python 
"/Users/nicolasdiaz/PycharmProjects/Marfil/lib/python3.10/Open files.py"
/Users/nicolasdiaz/Desktop/dtes copy/77116757-T33-F1877.xml
/Users/nicolasdiaz/Desktop/dtes copy/77116757-T33-F1960.xml
/Users/nicolasdiaz/Desktop/dtes copy/77116757-T33-F1961.xml
Factura:1961
Rut:93770000-8

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Place the last 2 *for* loops inside the 1st one (right indent them (and everything under) one level) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Move the two bottom for loops into the above one, like this:

   from os import listdir, path
   import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mypath = '/Users/nicolasdiaz/Desktop/dtes copy'
files = [path.join(mypath, f) for f in listdir(mypath) if f.endswith('.xml')]

for file in files:
print(file)
tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

```
for docID in root.iter('Folio'):
    Invoice = 'Factura:' + docID.text
    print(Invoice)
for client_rut in root.iter('RUTRecep'):
    Rut = 'Rut:' + client_rut.text
    print(Rut)
```

2. Create a dataframe before the for statement and in the loop, append to it using:

   df.append([file, Invoice, Rut])

Comment: Many thanks for your help, my problem right now it is that I have 3 different list, one for each xml, and I cant make a one data frame with the same data, but combined in rows and columns

    [Invoice1, Rut1]
    [Invoice2, Rut2]
    [Invoice3, Rut3] 

sorry but I am a beginner with python